# How to prevent file owned by root when using `sudo gedit`

Tags: permissions, launcher, root, gedit, ownership

When using `gedit` , i always need to edit file in `/etc/` or `/usr/` which need to be root. So i created a Launcher shortcut on the left with command `sudo gedit`.

So every time i click the icon on the left Launcher, `gedit` will started as root. But the problem is that, when i modified other files, such as files in `/home`, the owner of file will also be changed to root. I don't want to do this, i just want to save this file without modifying its owner, and i don't want to bother every time to restart `gedit` as root to modify files owned by root. How to do it?

Comment: You can change ownership of a file by executing `chown newusername /path/to/file`. If the file is currently owned by root or another user different from yours, you have to use it with sudo.

Comment: I don't want to chown every time I modify files

Comment: That is why I posted this as a comment and not as an answer. I don't think that gedit has an option like "save as user...". You only can create two different launchers (with and without gksu) then and edit the file with the respectively correct editor.

Comment: ehm... make a second launcher that does not have "sudo"? ;) but you really need to ask yourself a question: "why do you need to edit files in /etc/ or /usr/ so often?" I can not even remember the last time I needed to edit a file in there. Maybe  it was /etc/mysql/my.cnf but it has been months ago.

Comment: Extra: if the file is made by you and something personal I would  suggest considering placing it elsewhere. For instance /usr/local/ and change the owner from root to your user or place it in /home/$USER ; please try to limit altering files with admin as much as possible. Linux in general is set up such that alteration of files outside your own is not needed that often: you set up your system once and are done changing it unless you have some new software. In general all settings should have either a gui or should in in /home/ anyways.

Comment: @muru   I don't think it's a duplicate. Actually there is always someone says "This is duplicate". But the word "duplicate" should be defined by "question", not defined by "answer". Of course the answer of your link is that same as my question. But it doesn't mean my question is duplication of your question. Because , as long as a person even don't know keyword `gksudo`, it's really hard for him to search the answer.So my question and my title will be easier to search for someone who doesn't know `gksudo`

Comment: The problem is, your question is asking the wrong thing. The title "how to save a file as another user" is not answered by gksudo, and the actual question, "my files become owned by root, how do I prevent this" is covered by that question.

Comment: You're right,maybe now the title is better. But still, it's not a duplication. you should require to modify my title, not say it's a duplication

Comment: basically... if you don't want it to be owned by root... don't run it as root...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Add a shortcut to your launcher.

I would not change the main command of the `gedit` launcher. Do the following:

1. Never edit the default launcher, first copy the one from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/gedit.desktop
   ```
2. Edit the file with... gedit (not with `gksudo`)

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/gedit.desktop
   ```

   Look for the line, starting with `Actions=`, Add `gedit with gksu;`:

   ```
   Actions=Window;Document;gedit with gksu;
   ```
3. To the very end of the file add the shortcut section:

   ```
   [Desktop Action gedit with gksu]
   Name=gedit with gksu
   Exec=gksu gedit
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;
   ```
4. Done, Now if you click on the icon, `gedit` starts "normally", while you have `gksu gedit` available as a shortcut:

   [image]

---

#### Directly browse for a file to edit

If you often edit files with `gksu` with gedit, you can also directly call a (`Zenity`) browser from the launcher, to open your files with `gksu`. You can "save" one step when opening files with `gksu` then:

[image]

[image]

1. Copy & open the local `.desktop` file as in the first option
2. Look for the line, starting with `Actions=`, Add `gksu gedit with filebrowser;`:

   ```
   Actions=Window;Document;gksu gedit with filebrowser;
   ```
3. At the very end of the file, add the shortcut section:

   ```
   [Desktop Action gksu gedit with filebrowser]
   Name=gksu gedit with filebrowser
   Exec=sh -c "gksu gedit $(zenity --file-selection --title='Select a file')"
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;
   ```

#### Note

`gksu` is not installed by default, you will probably have to install it if you use the commands mentioned:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Comment: It's cool.I found `gksudo` before your post, and answered my own question but get downvoted. But when i use `gksudo`, sublime(my editor) always get non-response, so your post solved my problem perfectly!

Comment: Perfect! glad it works. If you *always* use `gksudo` (or gksu) instead of having it as an option, you still have the problem that files created are owned by root.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the owner by opening a terminal up and typing in `chown user /path/to/file  like Byte Commander stated you can do this.  However, setting the the owner isnt enough.  because you're accessing a root placed file in a root only access folder.  You need to give your self full permissions.

To make your self like root for that file only you need to type in a terminal

```
chmod u+aw filenamewithextension
```

You must do this while being in the file's location.

After this, you can gedit without sudo and never have the system modify the owner.  Do not `sudo gedit` or it will!

Comment: You probably wouldn't mess with the permissions of `/etc` for instance, nor with the files in it.